Different tyre manufactures on each wheel
I just bought a used car. When I inspected it, it still had winter tyres and the seller said he would find some summer tyres for it. Now I noticed that the summer tyres are not the all same brand. From a quick google search I found that this is not recommended. How severe is this, should I get new tyres myself or what should I be mindful of, to make sure the current tyres are a good fit? As far as I can tell, they're all the same size.

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Presumably the tyres that the dealer whipped together were a selection of used tyres (or they would match). If two are the same, you should fit them on the same 'axle'. Or you could take a view on the tread depth and general condition, and fit new tyres that you think the vehicle should have.

Read each tire sidewall for tire dimensions. The first three digit value is the width of the tire tread, the second two digit value is the profile - percentage of sidewall height to tire width, how high a sidewall is, and third is tire rim diameter. Trips around town should not affect steering and overall handling. Highway speed may affect steering and handling.  In general, tire width and aspect ratio (profile height) should not vary drastically.
